# CRM Console Application on MacOS

Tags: macos, dynamics-crm, console-application, crm, visual-studio-2019

I have Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 installed on a Mac running Mojave (10.14.4) and I am trying to create a simple C# Console Application to retrieve and update records in my CRM environment.

I am initializing a new instance of CrmServiceClient with the code below:

```
string connectionString = "authtype=Office365;username=*****************@**********.com;password=**********;url=https://**********.crm4.dynamics.com;";

CrmServiceClient conn = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);
```

On runtime, if I watch `conn` "isReady" property is “false” and there is an error message:

> "Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM OrganizationWebProxyClient is null"

This means I cannot initialize IOrganizationService and do the operations.

Additional info:

- I have already tried adding `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` with the same outcome
- Latest XRMTooling nugget package is added to the project
- Target framework is 4.6.2
- The same code works in VS running on Windows

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Dynamics SDK is based on .NET Framework 4.6.2 supports only Windows clients, this is the reason it doesn't work on MacOS

Comment: Thanks Guido, any word on when a .NET Core version of the SDK might arrive?

Comment: @Aron it's totally up to the team behind the SDK if and when they will release a .NET Core version